# Updating label text based on cell textLabel

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to capture the textLabel.text value of a cell in my tableView, and using nsuserdefaults, transferring it to another view. In this final view, a label should be updated with the captured value.

Here is my code from TableViewController.swift that captures the value:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //actions that will proceed immediately a cell row is clicked
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? PFTableViewCell

    //here I do the capture

    let captureCellVals = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    captureCellVals.setValue(cell?.textLabel?.text, forKey: "restoname")

    //code that transitions to the final view

    let view2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("finalView") as IndividualViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view2, animated: true)

}
```

And this is the code in the final view that is supposed to set the label's text value:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let values = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let resname = values.valueForKey("restoname")

    Restaurant.text = resname as? String

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


@IBOutlet var Restaurant: UILabel!
```

But for some reason, when I run it in the simulator, it crashes. No error report or nothing. Just a crash. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "??" nil coalescing operator to return an empty string in case you try to access it before storing any value to it:

```
Restaurant.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("restoname") ?? ""
```

Note. NSUserDefaults has a specific method for loading your stored string called [stringForKey()](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/stringForKey:)

Comment: So I tried that, but still the same thing happens. However, at the bottom left of Xcode this appears:                                                                      self EatSafeDC.IndividualViewController 0x00007f96e2c80890 0x00007f96e2c80890
values NSUserDefaults 0x3ff0000000000000 0x3ff0000000000000
resname String "I\x89\xc3f\x0foE\x80AYf\x0foM\x90AXf\x0foU\xa0Yf\x0fo]\xb0Zf\x0foe\xc0^f\x0fom\xd0_f\x0fou\xe0Xf\x0fo}\xf0\xc9M9\xdbA\xff\xe3ffffff.\x0f\x1f\x84"

Comment: Try printing the string before storing it

Comment: try using let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

Comment: I've just realized that setValue() still undocumented at Apple's website https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html

Answer (score -1):

So I figured it out.

It turns out that the problem was with the transition from the tableview to the final view. I needed to set the class for view2 as FinalView instead of IndividualViewController. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: This is not the way you should pass data from one controller to another. First of all, you shouldn't get data from a cell -- cells are for displaying data. You should get the data from your model based on the  indexPath. You should set the value of a property in your destination controller with the value you get from the model in prepareForSegue. You should not use NSUserDefaults for this purpose.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I was actually considering a prepareForSegue function, but the problem is that I only need the data to pass when the user activates a row. How would I go about doing what you're saying?

Comment: Make the segue from the cell to the next controller. In prepareForSegue:sender:, the sender will be the cell, so you can use the table view method indexPathForCell: to get the indexPath.

Comment: you just need to use the function `performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?)`
Then override the `prepareForSegue` function, check for the identifier, and then put the data you want on the destination ViewController